# How do I convert between a measure of similarity and a measure of difference (distance)?

Tags: metrics, string-comparison, levenshtein-distance

Is there a general way to convert between a measure of similarity and a measure of distance?

Consider a similarity measure like the number of 2-grams that two strings have in common.

```
2-grams('beta', 'delta') = 1
2-grams('apple', 'dappled') = 4
```

What if I need to feed this to an optimization algorithm that expects a measure of difference, like Levenshtein distance?

This is just an example...I'm looking for a general solution, if one exists.  Like how to go from Levenshtein distance to a measure of similarity?

I appreciate any guidance you may offer.

Comment: I am curious to know if your problem requires that the distance obeys [triangle inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) and if so which of these solutions you found most satisfactory.

Answer (score 13):

Let **d** denotes distance, **s** denotes similarity. To convert distance measure to similarity measure, we need to first normalize **d** to [0 1], by using **d_norm** = **d**/max(**d**). Then the similarity measure is given by:

**s** = 1 - **d_norm**.

where **s** is in the range [0 1], with 1 denotes highest similarity (the items in comparison are identical), and 0 denotes lowest similarity (largest distance).

Answer (score 6):

If your similarity measure (s) is between 0 and 1, you can use one of these:

```
1-s
sqrt(1-s)
-log(s)
(1/s)-1
```

Answer (score 5):

Doing 1/similarity is not going to keep the properties of the distribution.

the best way is 
distance (a->b) = highest similarity - similarity (a->b).
with highest similarity being the similarity with the biggest value. You hence flip your distribution. 
the highest similarity becomes 0 etc

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a **most general** way to change between *similarity* and *distance*: a **strictly monotone decreasing** function `f(x)`.

That is, with `f(x)` you can make `similarity = f(distance)` or `distance = f(similarity)`. It works in both directions. Such function works, because the relation between similarity and distance is that one decreases when the other increases.

**Examples:**

These are some well-known strictly monotone decreasing candidates that work for *non-negative* similarities or distances:

- `f(x) = 1 / (a + x)`
- `f(x) = exp(- x^a`)
- `f(x) = arccot(ax)`

You can choose parameter `a>0` (e.g., `a=1`)

> Edit 2021-08

A very practical approach is to use the function [sim2diss](https://rdrr.io/cran/smacof/man/sim2diss.html) belonging to the  [statistical software R](https://www.r-project.org/). This functions provides a up to 13 methods to compute dissimilarity from similarities. Sadly the methods are not at all explained: you have to [look into the code](https://rdrr.io/rforge/smacof/src/R/sim2diss.R) :-\

Comment: I have never seen: arccot(ax)

Comment: @user3352632 See at [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=arccot%28x%29) or at [wikipedia, inverse trigonometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)

Comment: I mean that somebody used it in a research paper

Comment: That's great. You (I, or whoever) can be the first to use arccot() as a relation between similarity and dissimilarity in a research and make history! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
similarity = 1/difference
```

and watch out for `difference = 0`

Comment: so one could try with `similarity = 1 / (difference + 1)`

Answer (score 1):

According to [scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#metrics):

Kernels are measures of similarity, i.e. s(a, b) > s(a, c) if objects a and b are considered “more similar” than objects a and c. A kernel must also be positive semi-definite.

There are a number of ways to convert between a distance metric and a similarity measure, such as a kernel. Let D be the distance, and S be the kernel:

- S = np.exp(-D * gamma), where one heuristic for choosing gamma is 1 /
  num_features
- S = 1. / (D / np.max(D))

Answer (score 0):

In the case of Levenshtein distance, you could increase the sim score by 1 for every time the sequences match; that is, 1 for every time you didn't need a deletion, insertion or substitution. That way the metric would be a linear measure of how many characters the two strings have in common.

Answer (score 0):

In one of my projects (based on Collaborative Filtering) I had to convert between correlation (cosine between vectors) which was from -1 to 1 (closer 1 is more similar, closer to -1 is more diverse) to normalized distance (close to 0 the distance is smaller and if it's close to 1 the distance is bigger)

In this case: distance ~ diversity

My formula was: `dist = 1 - (cor + 1)/2`

If you have similarity to diversity and the domain is [0,1] in both cases the simlest way is:

`dist = 1 - sim`

`sim = 1 - dist`

Answer (score 0):

[Cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) is  [widely used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model#Example:_tf-idf_weights)  for n-gram count or TFIDF vectors.

```
from math import pi, acos
def similarity(x, y):
    return sum(x[k] * y[k] for k in x if k in y) / sum(v**2 for v in x.values())**.5 / sum(v**2 for v in y.values())**.5
```

Cosine similarity can be used to compute a formal distance metric [according to wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). It obeys all the properties of a distance that you would expect (symmetry, nonnegativity, etc):

```
def distance_metric(x, y):
    return 1 - 2 * acos(similarity(x, y)) / pi
```

Both of these metrics range between 0 and 1.

If you have a [tokenizer](https://github.com/totalgood/twip/blob/master/twip/nlp.py) that produces N-grams from a string you could use these metrics like this:

```
>>> import Tokenizer
>>> tokenizer = Tokenizer(ngrams=2, lower=True, nonwords_set=set(['hello', 'and']))

>>> from Collections import Counter
>>> list(tokenizer('Hello World again and again?'))
['world', 'again', 'again', 'world again', 'again again']
>>> Counter(tokenizer('Hello World again and again?'))
Counter({'again': 2, 'world': 1, 'again again': 1, 'world again': 1})
>>> x = _
>>> Counter(tokenizer('Hi world once again.'))
Counter({'again': 1, 'world once': 1, 'hi': 1, 'once again': 1, 'world': 1, 'hi world': 1, 'once': 1})
>>> y = _
>>> sum(x[k]*y[k] for k in x if k in y) / sum(v**2 for v in x.values())**.5 / sum(v**2 for v in y.values())**.5
0.42857142857142855
>>> distance_metric(x, y)
0.28196592805724774
```

I found the elegant inner product of `Counter` in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18268940/623735)