# How do I run K-means algorithm on String objects?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, machine-learning, k-means

I am working on a project where I need to group sentences based on how similar they are.

For Example, these sentences need to be grouped into a single cluster:

1. Apple's monster Q1 earnings still fall short on Wall Street
2. Apple announces Q1 2013 earnings: record $54.5 billion in revenue.
3. Apple posts record revenue and profits; iPhone sales jump nearly 30%.

The titles keep coming in, so I might need to arrange and modify the clusters on the fly. Currently I am using the Monge-Elkan algorithm to identify how similar two strings are, but I don't know how to cluster them.

Searching on the internet leads me to believe that I need to use K-Means algorithm to group content, but I am not sure how to proceed with what I have.

What makes matters slightly complicated is the fact that I have hosted it on Google App Engine, so I can't use File System.

Comment: K-means depends on computing centroids. What would be the analog of an average via Monge-Elkan distances?

Comment: I have about 1000 sentences to process and with Monge-Elkan, I am able to calcutate the relative similarities between any two given strings. How do I calculate the average distance for the entire dataset?

Comment: Average distances aren't what you want. What you want is a concept of an "average" of sentences. What would that mean?

Comment: Sorry, being new to data mining, I don't know how I could find out "Average" of sentences. Would you please highlight with an example - if not provide me the links where I can find it.

Comment: It is very easy to over-think a problem in data mining. In this case although we will end up identifying centroids the locations of those centroids is unimportant, all that matters is the partitioning of which sentence goes to which centroid.

Comment: What will you set K to for K-means? As someone with decades of data mining experience let me point out your goal is to produce actionable knowledge, not more data. There are statistical tests for calculating an optimum value for K, but if a human being must use the result directly, the actionable optimum is always less than 10 as that is what real people can cope with. If you are passing data into another data mining system, use many values of K and let the down-stream system choose what it likes best.

Comment: @user1117972 - No, you don't understand: I'm asking **you** what **you** mean by the "average" of a set of sentences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit distance metrics are unlikely to effectively model the similarity of the meaning of sentences, which I assume you are after. Same goes for the low-level representation of text as a string of characters.

A better approach is to use a higher-level representation, such as the [vector-space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model). Here you collect all the unique words in your sentence collection(corpus) and map each of them to a number. Each document(sentence) is then represented as a vector:

[w1_count, w2_count, ..., wN_count]

Where N'th element is the count of N'th word (the word mapped to number N) in given sentence.

Now you can run k-means on this dataset, but better:

1. Process the data so that the important words such as 'Apple' are given more weight that common words such as 'on' or 'in'. One such technique is [TF-IDF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). Then run standard k-means on this with euclidean distance.
2. Even better, use an even higher-level tool such as [Latent Semantic Analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_analysis) or [Latent Dirichlet Allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation).

If you want to use your existing approach, Simon G.'s answer points you in the right direction and similarity to distance coversion is answered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064630/how-do-i-convert-between-a-measure-of-similarity-and-a-measure-of-difference-di).

Comment: What do you do if the sentences are of varying length?  Doesn't k-means require the vectors to be of the same length?

Comment: Each vector contains counts not only for words in the sentence but for the whole collection of sentences. That results in a sparse dataset (where most of the values in the vector are zero) but the vector length is constant and equals the count of all the words in the dataset.

Answer (score 2):

First, change your similarities into dissimlarities so that they can be thought of as distances

Second, use a multidimensional scaling library to change the distances into points in space.

Third, use regular k-means on the points in space.

Comment: Ok, I could you http://www.inf.uni-konstanz.de/algo/software/mdsj/ for multidimensional scaling, but how can I change similarities into dissimilarities.

Comment: Monge-Elkan is built on top of some other similarity measure. How you transform similarities into distances depends on how that other similarity measure works. If two exactly equal tokens always have a similarity of 1 and two completely different tokens always have a similarity of 0, just use (1-similarity). The main things are: distances are always positive, and two equal things are 0 distance apart.