# Gensim: word mover distance with string as input instead of list of string

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I'm trying to find out how similar are 2 sentences.
For doing it i'm using gensim word mover distance and since what i'm trying to find it's a similarity i do like it follow:

```
sim = 1 - wv.wmdistance(sentence_obama, sentence_president)
```

What i give as an input are 2 strings:

```
    sentence_obama = 'Obama speaks to the media in Illinois'
    sentence_president = 'The president greets the press in Chicago'
```

The model i'm using is the one that you can find on the web: word2vec-google-news-300
I load it with this code:

```
wv = api.load("word2vec-google-news-300")
```

It give me reasonable results.
Here it's where the problem starts.
For what i can read from the documentation [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/tutorials/run_wmd.html) it seems the wmd take as input a list of string and not a string like  i do!

```
def preprocess(sentence):
   return [w for w in sentence.lower().split() if w not in stop_words]

sentence_obama = preprocess(sentence_obama)
sentence_president = preprocess(sentence_president)
sim = 1 - wv.wmdistance(sentence_obama, sentence_president)
```

When i follow the documentation i get results really different:

```
wmd using string as input: 0.5562025871542842
wmd using list of string as input: -0.0174646259300113
```

I'm really confused. Why is it working with string as input and it works better than when i give what the documentation is asking for?

Answer (score 1):

The function needs a list-of-string-tokens to give proper results: if your results pasing full strings look good to you, it's pure luck and/or poor evaluation.

So: why do you consider `0.556` to be a better value than `-0.017`?

Since passing the texts as plain strings means they are interpreted as lists-of-single-characters, the value there is going to be a function of how different the letters in the two texts are - and the fact that all English sentences of about the same length have very similar letter-distributions, means most texts will rate as very-similar under that error.

Also, similarity or distance values mainly have meaning in comparison to *other pairs of sentences*, not two different results from different processes (where one of them is essentially random). You shouldn't consider absolute values that are exceeding some set threshold, or close to `1.0`, as definitively good. You should instead consider relative differences, between two similarity/distance values, to mean one pair is more similary/distant than another pair.

Finally: converting a distance (which goes from `0.0` for closest to infinity for furthest) to a similarity (which typically goes from `1.0` for most-similar to `-1.0` or `0.0` for least-similar) is **not** usefully done via the formula you're using, `similarity = 1.0 - distance`. Because a distance can be larger than 2.0, you could have arbitrarily negative similarities with that approach, and be fooled to think `-0.017` (etc) is bad, because it's negative, even if it's quite good across all the possible return values.

Some more typical distance-to-similarity conversions are given in another SO question:

[How do I convert between a measure of similarity and a measure of difference (distance)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064630/how-do-i-convert-between-a-measure-of-similarity-and-a-measure-of-difference-di)